# Modeling beta distributed data using glmmTBM

Tags: regression, beta-distribution, glmmtmb

I have been trying to model this beta distributed data for a bit now with no success. It doesn't seem to be zero-one inflated visually, but I do have some ones in my data.

Here is the description of [`my data`](https://github.com/KatherineDuchesneau/miscellaneous/blob/master/KD_DATA) (based on this [answer by Alexander](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28292/does-my-data-come-from-a-gamma-or-beta-distribution)):

```
>summary(y)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.0300  0.4625  0.6700  0.6229  0.8000  1.0000 

>plot(density(y))
```

[image: plot]

```
>mu <- mean(y)
>var <- var(y)
>estBetaParams <- function(mu, var) {
+  alpha <- ((1 - mu) / var - 1 / mu) * mu ^ 2
+  beta <- alpha * (1 / mu - 1)
+  return(params = list(alpha = alpha, beta = beta))
+}
>estBetaParams(mu, var)

$alpha
[1] 2.446421

$beta
[1] 1.4812
```

So when I try to run a model as recommended [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248045/how-to-implement-a-mixed-model-using-betareg-function-in-r) by Kori Khan and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167340/beta-regression-with-random-effect-of-source-plot-in-two-seasons?noredirect=1&lq=1) by Ben Bolker, I get this error message:

```
 >library(glmmTMB)
 >mod1.beta<-glmmTMB(y~ a + b + a:b +
 +                     (1|g),
 +                   data=df, family=list(family="beta",link="logit")) 


  Error in nlminb(start = par, objective = fn, gradient = gr, control =             
  control$optCtrl) : 
    gradient function must return a numeric vector of length 6
  In addition: Warning message:
  In nlminb(start = par, objective = fn, gradient = gr, control =       
  control$optCtrl) :
    NA/NaN function evaluation
  Timing stopped at: 0.023 0.004 0.028
```

Does someone understand why this model fails? On the [Troubleshooting page for glmmTMB of the CRAN website](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/troubleshooting.html) it says that this occurs because the beta distribution is not appropriate with negative values but I have no negative values in my response variable.

I have been looking into adding zero-one inflation into the model because I have 1.00s in y, but I'm not sure if I have enough 1.00s to qualify for a one-inflated beta distribution. If I do I'm not sure how to go about specifying it in the code and haven't been able to find an example of how to integrate that into the model anywhere.

Thank you.

Comment: It's because you have 1's in your response variable. For beta regression, the response variable needs to satisfy $y\in(0,1)$. [Cribari-Neto & Zeileis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf) recommend using the transformation $(y(n - 1) + 0.5)/n$ where $n$ is the sample size in cases where 0's or 1's are present in the response variable $y$.

Comment: I just found this question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/dealing-with-0-1-values-in-a-beta-regression) thats very similar to mine now that I understand what the problem is! Thank you!