# Does the beta distribution have a conjugate prior?

Tags: beta-distribution, conjugate-prior

I know that the beta distribution is conjugate to the binomial. But what is the conjugate prior of the beta? Thank you.

Comment: If one works with one parameter fixed, say Beta$(\theta,1)$, then a conjugate prior for $\theta$ is a Gamma distribution.

Comment: Also see the question [Random number generation for conjugate distribution of beta distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485170/random-number-generation-for-conjugate-distribution-of-beta-distribution).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems that you already gave up on conjugacy. Just for the record, one thing that I've seen people doing (but don't remember exactly where, sorry) is a reparameterization like this. If $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are conditionally iid, given $\alpha,\beta$, such that $X_i\mid\alpha,\beta\sim\mathrm{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$, remember that
$$
  \mathbb{E}[X_i\mid\alpha,\beta]=\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta} =: \mu
$$
and
$$
  \mathbb{Var}[X_i\mid\alpha,\beta] = \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^2(\alpha+\beta+1)} =: \sigma^2 \, .
$$
Hence, you may [reparameterize](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12239/9394) the likelihood in terms of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ and use as a prior
$$
  \sigma^2\mid\mu \sim \mathrm{U}[0,\mu(1-\mu)] \qquad \qquad \mu\sim\mathrm{U}[0,1] \, .
$$
Now you're ready to compute the posterior and explore it by your favorite computational method.

Comment: No, not MCMC this thing!  Quadrature this thing! only 2 parameters - quadrature is the "gold standard" for small dimensional posteriors, both for time and accuracy.

Comment: Another option is to regard $\psi = \alpha + \beta$ as a measure of precision, and again use $\mu = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}$ as an the mean. This is done all the time with Dirichlet processes, and the beta distribution is a special case. So  maybe toss a gamma or log-normal prior on $\psi$ and uniform on $\mu$.

Comment: To be sure, this isn't conjugate, correct?

Comment: Definitely not!

Comment: Hi @Zen i'm dealing with this problem right now, but i'm new at Bayesian and im not sure if im understanding the idea. I figured out that you're proposing to find $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{1}{\mu(1-\mu}}d\mu$ and then use reparametrization, but of course that Was not the idea. Can you please help me to understand?

Comment: Another option is to parameterize by "concentration", $c = \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}$, which scales independent of the mean.  [Velten et al., 2015](http://msb.embopress.org/content/11/6/812) use this with uniform prior on the mean and log-normal prior on $c$. Details are in [their supplement (PDF)](http://msb.embopress.org/content/msb/11/6/812/DC1/embed/inline-supplementary-material-1.pdf?download=true).

Comment: @Zen can you clarify what is the purpose of this reparameterization? How is this more helpful than working in the original parameterization?

Comment: @probabilityislogic Does quadrature mean numerical integration, or something different (or perhaps something more specific)?

Comment: I think he/she means this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_quadrature

Comment: Interestingly, the model proposed in this answer corresponds to parametrising the Beta distribution in terms of mean $\mu=\alpha/(\alpha+\beta)$ and sample size $\nu=\alpha+\beta$ and setting $\mu \sim U[0,1]$ and $\nu+1 \sim \mathrm{Pareto}(\alpha=1,x_m=1)$. This is because $\sigma^2=\mu(1-\mu)/(\nu + 1)$ and placing a uniform [0,1] distribution for $\sigma^2 / [\mu(1-\mu)]$ corresponds to a Pareto on $\nu + 1$.

Answer (score 33):

Yes, it has a conjugate prior in the exponential family. Consider the three parameter family
$$
\pi(\alpha, \beta \mid a, b, p) 
\propto \left\{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\right\}^p 
    \exp\left(a\alpha + b\beta \right).
$$
For some values of $(a, b, p)$, this is integrable, although I haven't quite figured out which ones (I believe $p \ge 0$ and $a < 0, b < 0$ should work — $p = 0$ corresponds to independent exponential distributions so that definitely works; moreover, the conjugate update involves incrementing $p$ so this suggests that $p > 0$ works as well).

The problem, and at least part of the reason no one uses it, is that
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \left\{\frac{\Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\right\}^p 
    \exp\left(a\alpha + b\beta \right) = ?
$$
i.e. the normalizing constant doesn't have a closed form.

Comment: Ah. That is problematic. I was going to look for an uninformative version of the conjugate prior anyway, so looks like I might as well start with uniform priors over the two parameters. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to normalize it if you're just comparing likelihoods…

Comment: I think you might be missing the action of $p$ in your $\exp$ term as well.  It should probably be $pa\alpha$, etc.

Comment: @NeilG $p$ is in the $\exp$, you just have to express things in terms of $\log \Gamma(\cdots)$ instead of $\Gamma(\cdots)$. Doing $pa\alpha$ is just a reparmetrization, it changes nothing. Not sure what you mean "just comparing likelihoods". You can't implement a Gibbs sampler with this prior without using something like Metropolis, which kills the advantage of conditional conjugacy, the normalizing constant depends on $a$ and $b$ which kills putting a prior on them or estimating them by likelihood methods, etc...

Comment: You're right that putting $p$ there is a reparameterization.  However, should that be a triple integral, since you want to integrate over all three parameters… and $a$ and $b$ as you have them should be negative so two of the integrals should run over the negative reals.

Comment: @NeilG integral is over $\alpha$ and $\beta$ since those are the random variables.

Comment: Ah, you're right!  Not sure what I was thinking…

Comment: Does this type of prior assume $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are independent? What if they are not?

Comment: Couldn't we assume that $a, b < 0$, since the exponential distribution is only defined for negative values of the rate parameter in the exponent?

Answer (score 11):

In *theory* there should be a conjugate prior for the beta distribution. This is because

- the beta distribution is one of the [exponential family distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family), and
- in theory it should be possible to derive a prior. See, e.g., [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Bayesian_estimation%3a_conjugate_distributions), [D Blei's lecture on exponential families](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597C/lectures/exponential-families.pdf).

However the derivation looks difficult, and to quote [A Bouchard-Cote's Exponential Families and Conjugate Priors](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.118.8315&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

> An important observation to make is that this recipe does not always yields
>   a conjugate prior that is computationally tractable.

Consistent with this, there is no prior for the Beta distribution in [D Fink's A Compendium of Conjugate Priors](http://www.johndcook.com/CompendiumOfConjugatePriors.pdf).

Comment: The derivation is not difficult — See my answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63496/what-can-be-said-about-an-infinite-linear-chain-of-conjugate-prior-distributions/65203#65203

Answer (score 6):

Robert and Casella (RC) happen to describe the family of conjugate priors of the beta distribution in Example 3.6 (p 71 - 75) of their book, *Introducing Monte Carlo Methods in R*, Springer, 2010. However, they quote the result without citing a source.

**Added in response to gung's request for details.** RC state that for distribution $B(\alpha, \beta)$, the conjugate prior is "... of the form

$$ \pi(\alpha,\beta) \propto  \Big\{ \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} {\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \Big\} ^{\lambda} x_0^{\alpha} y_0^{\beta} $$

where $\{\lambda, x_0, y_0\}$ are hyperparameters, since the posterior is then equal to

$$ \pi(\alpha,\beta \vert x) \propto  \Big\{ \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)} {\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \Big\} ^{\lambda} (xx_0)^{\alpha} ((1-x)y_0)^{\beta}." $$

The remainder of the example concerns importance sampling from $\pi(\alpha,\beta \vert x)$ in order to compute the marginal likelihood of $x$.

Comment: I don't have Robert's book available but the posterior is $\pi(\alpha, \beta) \propto \left( \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} \right)^{\lambda +1} (x x_0)^{\alpha-1} \left(y_0 (1-x) \right)^{\beta-1}$. Robert also posted on this topic here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20399/conjugate-prior-of-the-dirichlet-distribution#comment553934_20875

Comment: I humbly recommend that the original poster updates the post to indicate that the posterior given in the textbook is incorrect, per Fred Schoen's comment (which is easily verified).

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a "standard" (i.e., exponential family) distribution that is the conjugate prior for the beta distribution.  However, if one does exist it would have to be a bivariate distribution.

Comment: I have no idea about this question, but I did find this handy conjugate prior map that seems to support your answer: http://www.johndcook.com/conjugate_prior_diagram.html

Comment: The conjugate prior is in the exponential family and has three parameters — not two.

Comment: @Neil, you are definitely right.  I guess I should have said it would have to have at least two parameters.

Comment: -1: this answer is clearly wrong in the claim that "conjugate prior does not exist in the exponential family", as is demonstrated in the [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/67511/163572) above...