# Bayesian priors and probability distributions

Tags: bayesian, prior, beta-distribution, conjugate-prior

Book "Bayesian Statistics the Fun Way: Understanding Statistics and Probability
with Star Wars, Lego, and Rubber Ducks", chapter 9 "Bayesian priors and working
with probability distributions".

In the chapter, the author tried to demonstrate how to "use probability
distributions to numerically describe our beliefs as a range of possible values
rather than single values".

The author used the scene in *Star Wars: the Empire Strikes Back* where Han
Solo, attempting to evade enemy fighters, files the Millennium Falcon into an
asteroid field as an example.

The author suggested that the posterior (Han making through the asteroid field)
is calculated from the C-3PO beliefs (likelihood) and our beliefs in Han's
badassery (prior).

Here a summarized of steps the author proposed to calculate the posterior:

1. Likelihood

"Sir, the possibility of successfully navigating an asteroid field is
approximately 3,720 to 1!"

The author suggested to use **beta distribution**:

> Because C-3PO provides the *approximate* odds of successfully navigating an
> asteroid field, we know that the data he has gives him only enough
> information to suggest a range of possible rates of success. To represent that
> range, we need to look at a *distribution* of beliefs regarding the
> probability of success, rather than a single value representing the
> probability.

Then the author provided the formula:

> P(RateOfSuccess | Successes and Failures) = $Beta(\alpha, \beta)$

From what I understand, apply that to the problem mean:

Let RateOfSuccess_likelihood = The success rate of navigating an asteroid field
is approximately 3,720 to 1

P(RateOfSuccess_likelihood | succeses and failures) =
$Beta(\alpha_{likelihood}, \beta_{likelihood})$

The author then gave an assumption: $\alpha$ = 2, $\beta$ = 7400

2. Prior

The author also suggested to use **beta distribution** to model the prior
beliefs.

Given Han's badassery (plot armor), the author assumed: $\alpha$ = 20000,
$\beta$ = 1

Therefore:

Let RateOfSuccess_prior = The success rate of navigating an asteroid field is
approximately 2 to 20000

P(RateOfSuccess_prior | successes and failures) = $Beta(\alpha_{prior},\beta_{prior})$

3. Posterior

The author tried to use the formula discussed in previous chapter to calculate
the posterior distribution:

> Posterior $\propto$ Likelihood $\times$ Prior
>
> Remember, using this proportional form of Bayes' theorem means that our
> posterior distribution doesn't necessarily sum to 1. But we're lucky because
> there's an easy way to combine beta distributions that will give us a
> *normalized* posterior when all we have is the likelihood and the prior.
> Combining our two beta distributions - one representing C-3PO's data (the
> likelihood) and the other our prior belief in Han's ability to survive
> anything (our prior) - in this way is remarkably easy:
>
> $
>  Beta(\alpha_{posterior},\beta_{posterior}) = 
>  Beta(\alpha_{likelihood}+\alpha_{prior},\beta_{likelihood}+\beta_{prior})
>  $

The author comes up with the formula

$Beta(\alpha_{posterior},\beta_{posterior}) = Beta(\alpha_{likelihood}+ \alpha_{prior}, 
\beta_{likelihood}+ \beta_{prior})$

without any explanation.

This is the part where I don't understand. **How can the author comes up with
the above formula?**

---

Here my attempts to figure out:

1. Substitutes beta distribution formula

Posterior $\propto$ Likelihood $\times$ Prior,

$\rightarrow Beta(\alpha_{posterior}, \beta_{posterior})$

$= Beta(\alpha_{likelihood}, \beta_{likelihood}) \times Beta(\alpha_{prior},\beta_{prior})$

$= x^{\alpha_{likelihood}- 1}(1 - x)^{\beta_{likelihood}- 1}x^{\alpha_{prior}- 1}(1 - x)^{\beta_{prior}- 1}$

$= x^{\alpha_{likelihood}+ \alpha_{prior}- 2}(1 - x)^{\beta_{likelihood}+ \beta_{prior}- 2}$

$= Beta(\alpha_{likelihood}+ \alpha_{prior}- 1, \beta_{likelihood}+ \beta_{prior}- 1)$

which is different with the formula the author come up with.

2. After some further search from the Internet, I found some links to articles related to the problem. Here are two of them:

[Conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior)

[Help me understand Bayesian prior and posterior distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/help-me-understand-bayesian-prior-and-posterior-distributions)

The result formula in these links are similar to that of the author. E.g:

[image: Posterior distribution]

Which is equivalent to $Beta(s + \alpha, f + \beta)$ which is similar to the formula the author came up with $Beta(\alpha_{likelihood}+ \alpha_{prior}, 
\beta_{likelihood}+ \beta_{prior})$

However, in these articles and the others I have found, the **likelihood** is **binomial**
rather than **beta distribution** as suggested by the author. **Why?**

Is the author wrong or the examples in the book and the links I found are
different cases? I would appreciate any explanation (i.e. How the author come up with the formula) and/or link to articles mentioned usages of Bayes' theorem and **beta distribution likelihood**.

(Most of my knowledge in statistics comes from self-education, thus I still
have many gaps in understanding concepts that may seem trivial for other people
here. So I would be very thankful if answers included less specific terms and
more explanation).

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, [beta is a conjugate prior for binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution) distribution. On another hand, [beta *is not* conjugate prior for beta](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67443/does-the-beta-distribution-have-a-conjugate-prior) distribution, so there is no simple, closed-form, solution for the posterior of such model.

So if $k$ is the *number of successes* and $n$ is the *total number of trials* (hence $n-k$ is the number of failures), then we can use binomial as a likelihood

$$
k|p \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n, p)
$$

and beta as a prior

$$
p \sim \mathsf{Beta}(\alpha, \beta)
$$

then the posterior would be

$$
p | k \sim \mathsf{Beta}(\alpha + k, \beta + n - k)
$$

Maybe, what author means is that C3PO’s distribution is a *prior* and then the description jumps to describing posterior, while skipping the likelihood part?

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the answer. I found [the article](https://www.countbayesie.com/blog/2015/2/18/hans-solo-and-bayesian-priors) by the author that the chapter in the book is based on. Could you reconfirm whether it is the author wrong or I misunderstand something? (I'm concerned that because I misunderstand something, my question does not capture exactly what the author means). Thank you very much.

Comment: @SweetPotato see my edit for possible interpretation

Comment: In the article, the author said: "In Bayesian terms, C3PO's estimate of the true rate of success given observed data is referred to as the _Likelihood_", "We have now established what C3PO believes (Likelihood) and modeled our own beliefs in Han (Prior Probability), but we need a way to combine these. " and "It also turns out that **combining our two Beta distributions** in this way, including the normalization, is remarkably easy."

Comment: @SweetPotato so either it is an error or the description is just confusing. Otherwise, this would be incorrect, as stated in the answer.