# What's a sensible way to put a credible interval on samples in [0, 1]?

Tags: bayesian, credible-interval

Say I take a bunch of measurements of a discrete random variable in {0, 1} (coin flips of a weighted coin for instance). I understand that a reasonable way to report on the mean and credible interval is to introduce a uniform beta distribution as a prior and treat each coin flip as a bayesian update. The resulting expectation value is slightly less aggressive (less towards either 0 or 1) than a straight average, and the confidence interval can be computed via the inverse cdf.

Right, now let's say I have a continuous random variable in [0, 1]. What's the analogous "reasonable" way to do the above? I don't think it's to use a guassian prior because this has a few issues:

1. It has non-zero probability outside of [0, 1].
2. The expectation value may be overly-aggressive. Getting a single 1 would give an expectation value of 1 which feels unfair.
3. I've found the error bars are far wider than the Bernoulli version above, given the same number of experiments.

Comment: If you are using Bayesian approaches you could reduce some potential confusion by replacing "confidence interval" with "credible interval" throughout the question. "Confidence interval" is usually taken to be a frequentist concept. See [Wikipedia on Credible interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval). Have you considered a uniform distribution over [0,1] as  a prior?

Comment: What distributional assumptions are you making about your random variable and what property do you need a confidence interval for?

Comment: @EdM thanks, I'll accept the edit. I was looking for a distribution that has a conjugate prior so that the updates stay neat like in the beta distrubtion. After all, I just want to put meaningful error bars on a plot that shows the score of a reinforcement learning model over multiple experiements.

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure really. I just know that there's a really nice approach to take in the Bernoulli case so why shouldn't there be one here. But maybe the answer is that my scenario is just fundamentally different.

Comment: The Bernoulli case requires only one parameter to describe, whence it has essentially only one property.  The situation you posit here cannot be described by any finite number of parameters, whence no finite number of properties can (in general) identify a single distribution.  That's an *enormous* difference, which is why you need to be more specific about both the distributional assumptions and the properties of interest.

Comment: The most commonly assumed distribution for [0,1] data is probably the beta distribution. It has a conjugate prior (see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485170/random-number-generation-for-conjugate-distribution-of-beta-distribution), though it's not got a nice closed form density. One approach would be to make a beta likelihood assumption with Conjugate prior and then form empirical credible interval estimates using the Monte Carlo method in proposed in the answer to the linked question.