# Beta-Binomial mixture vs Beta-Binomial multilevel model?

Tags: mixed-model, binomial-distribution, beta-distribution, conjugate-prior, beta-binomial-distribution

I first read about the Beta PDF in the context that it was conjugate to the Binomial distribution; [a Beta prior with a Binomial likelihood returns a Beta posterior](https://towardsdatascience.com/conjugate-prior-explained-75957dc80bfb). So this sounds to me like a multilevel model. However, I've come across the [Beta-Binomial PMF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution).

Differences I've noticed:
Beta-Binomial conj prior is continuous and a closed form MAP solution exists. The Beta-Binomial mixture is discrete and an MLE solution exists.

Beyond these simple observations, I'm not sure when each would/wouldn't be appropriate and how they differ. Thoughts? Is there a deeper relationship here or is it just inconvenient that they have such similar names?

Edit: In response to Tim's answer, I've added the below from my comment on his answer:

Follow up, I see that among PyMC3's discrete likelihood functions [Beta-Binomial](https://docs.pymc.io/en/stable/api/distributions/discrete.html#pymc3.distributions.discrete.BetaBinomial) is built in. Given what you've said. When would I use the Binomial likelihood vs the Beta-Binomial likelihood, both assuming a Beta prior? And how do these differences affect terms of the posterior-predictive distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both pieces of the beta-binomial *model*. In beta-binomial model, the predicted variable $y$ follows the binomial distribution, where the number of samples $n$ is known and we want to learn the "probability of success" $p$. For this, we are using a Bayesian model, where beta distribution with hyperparameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ serves as a prior for $p$:

$$\begin{align}
p &\sim \mathsf{Beta}(\alpha, \beta) \\
y &\sim \mathsf{Binomial}(n, p)
\end{align}$$

In such a case, due to conjugacy, the [posterior distribution for $p$ is also beta distributed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/47771/what-is-the-intuition-behind-beta-distribution). On another hand, the [posterior predictive distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution), i.e. the distribution for your predictions of $\hat y$, is [beta-binomial *distribution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution).

Comment: Follow up, I see that among PyMC3's discrete likelihood functions Beta-Binomial (https://docs.pymc.io/en/stable/api/distributions/discrete.html#pymc3.distributions.discrete.BetaBinomial) is built in. Given what you've said. When would I use the Binomial likelihood vs the Beta-Binomial likelihood, both assuming a Beta prior?

Comment: @jbuddy_13 The beta-binomial distribution can be used to describe [over/under-dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overdispersion#Binomial). The conjugate prior distribution won't be a beta distribution. I imagine that it will be something complex, already the conjugate distribution of the beta distribution is something difficult: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/67511

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus & Tim, I've made some rather large changes to this post in reference to both of your insightful comments. Curious on your thoughts about inference and inconsistency of parameters...

Comment: @jbuddy it might be better if you undo the changes (you can go back to a previous version) and post an entirely new question.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus, done! https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/550811/inconsistent-posterior-estimates-in-beta-binomial-likelihood-vs-binomial-in-baye