# References for the conjugate prior to the beta distribution?

Tags: bayesian, references, prior, beta-distribution, conjugate-prior

The Wikipedia article about "Conjugate Prior" has a table containing information about Likelihood Distributions with their Conjugate Priors.

In the "Continuous Likelihood" table, the last entry shows a Beta Likelihood and a formula for a Conjugate Prior, (with 3 hyperparameters: p, q, k).

Can anybody give pointers to literature on this?

I did check the key reference given in Wikipedia: "A Compendium of Conjugate Priors" by Daniel Fink.  Couldn´t find it there or anywhere else.

Comment: This question would be clearer if you [edit]ed to include the probability distribution for which you would like to have a reference.

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) conjugate prior for $(\alpha,\beta)$ of a Beta distribution namely  a density $\propto \dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)^k \, p^\alpha \, q^\beta}{\Gamma(\alpha)^k\,\Gamma(\beta)^k}$ is fairly clearly correct as each new observation  multiplies this by the likelihood $\dfrac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta) \, x^\alpha \, (1-x)^\beta}{\Gamma(\alpha)\,\Gamma(\beta)}$ i.e. adds $1$ to $k$, multiplies $p$ by $x$ and multiplies $q$ by $1-x$.

Comment: Hi: Here's another thread that has some information. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67443/does-the-beta-distribution-have-a-conjugate-prior