# $\sigma^2 \le (\mu-a)(b-\mu)$ for all probability distributions bounded on $[a,b]$?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, probability-inequalities

Let $\mu$ be the mean and $\sigma$ the standard deviation of a probability distribution defined on the bounded interval $[a,b]$ (that is, the probability that the random variable lies outside $[a,b]$ is zero).

Does the following inequality hold generally for any such probability distribution?

$$\sigma^2 \le (\mu-a)(b-\mu)$$

**Motivation:** This inequality holds for the Beta distribution (as is obvious from the formulae [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/93479/5536)).