# What does this mean "the standard deviation of a proportion is a function of the proportion itself"?

Tags: proportion, statistical-power

I was studying calculating power and sample sizes and i came across this paragraph:

> Calculating Power for comparing two proportions has the same idea as
>   with comparing means, except that no standard deviation estimate is
>   necessary (as the standard deviation of a proportion is a function of
>   the proportion itself)

what does the sentence between the parenthesis mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mean of a proportion is p, then the variance is $p(1-p)$. The standard deviation is then the square root.

This clearly shows what is meant by a "function of itself". Once you have the proportion you also have the variance.

Using the sample analogy principle it can, with ease, be shown that sample variance (estimate) is: $\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$.

The version I had (pre edit) was divided by n. This is interesting if you wish to do testing, or calculate a confidence interval

Comment: I believe the quote refers to the variance of a sample proportion; the variance of a sample proportion is $p(1-p)/n$.

Comment: Yeah I suppose, still same principle

Comment: The variance of a sample proportion is $p(1-p)/n$, which depends on $p$, not $\hat{p}$. The version with $\hat{p}$ is simply a sample estimate of the "true" variance of the estimate. If you're going to keep "the variance is $p(1-p)$" in your first sentence you'll need to clarify what you intend it to be the variance *of*.

Comment: are you sure that it can be shown that the sample variance of a proportion is $\frac{\hat{p} (1-\hat{p})}{n}$ ?  With $\hat{p}$ the estimated proportion ?  I think I must agree with @Glen_b (+1)

Comment: The relation given is not a completely general relation for any kind of distribution for proportions, but it is the relation for a binomial. Another  interesting case is the beta distribution (see e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12232/calculating-the-parameters-of-a-beta-distribution-using-the-mean-and-variance). More positively, there must be a qualitative dependence of variance on the mean for proportions, as the variance will be zero if the mean proportion is 0 or 1 but will be positive otherwise, apart from degenerate cases.