# Given a mean, what is the range of variance values that make for possible Beta distribution parameters

Tags: estimators, beta-distribution, conjugate-prior, derivative

The beta distribution can have its parameter [estimated via method of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), which I will be doing.

$$\hat\alpha = \bigg(\dfrac{\bar x (1-\bar x)}{var(X)} - 1\bigg)\bar{x}\\
\hat\beta = \bigg(\dfrac{\bar x (1-\bar x)}{var(X)} - 1\bigg)(1-\bar{x})
$$

I have the mean but not the variance. **How can I calculate the range of variance values that result in possible $(\hat\alpha, \hat\beta)$ vectors (both components positive)?**

My attempt was with some calculus to find maxima and minima, and it did not go well.

$$
\hat\alpha(v\vert \bar x) = \bigg(\dfrac{\bar x (1-\bar x)}{v} - 1\bigg)\bar{x} = \dfrac{\bar x^2 (1-\bar x)}{v} - \bar x\\
\dfrac{d\hat\alpha}{dv} = -\dfrac{\bar x^2 (1-\bar x)}{v^2} = 0\\
\bar x^2(1-\bar x) = 0\\
\bar x = 0, 1
$$
My $\bar x$ is not going to be $0$ or $1$, and this approach loses the variance $v$.

(The reason I have the mean but not the variance is because I am using the beta as a prior for the $p$ parameter of a binomial variable, and I know what I want as the mean of my prior, but I do not know the variance. I want to know what variance values I can pick and if suggested values will be off-limits.)

Comment: The [bound on the variance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12239/7224) is $$\text{var}(X)<\mu(1-\mu)$$

Comment: @Xi'an Helpful! Is $\mu(1-\mu)$ the least upper bound on $\text{var}(X)?$

Comment: @Glen_b Typo corrected.